# DAX formula to filter on Max Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

Good Day,

I have an issue where a MAXX(Date) DAX formula is not ouputting correctly.

Essentially I wrote formulas to calculate the value of items from a previous month, which ouputs correctly. Now I want to filter on the MAX selected date (wrote this in DAX) for those values but it does not work.

Apologies - neglected to add the formula.

Latest Month =

VAR CurrentYearMonth =

MAXX(ALLSELECTED('tertiary vw_insights_ageing_profile'),'tertiary vw_insights_ageing_profile'[Date Link])

Return IF(max('tertiary vw_insights_ageing_profile'[Date Link]) = CurrentYearMonth,1,0)

Also tried

Latest Month =

VAR CurrentYearMonth = MAXX(ALLSELECTED('tertiary vw_insights_ageing_profile'),'tertiary vw_insights_ageing_profile'[Date Link])
Return

IF(format(max('tertiary vw_insights_ageing_profile'[Date Link]),"YYYYMM") = format(CurrentYearMonth,"YYYYMM"),1,0)

Visual Ouputs

[image: 1]

1. The matrix output on the far left is correct
2. The table output in the
   middle via a DAX filter does not work  ([Latest Month], [Date
   Checker]) Code can be found in PowerBI file
3. The table output on the
   right (manual filter) works perfectly.

I'm not sure where the formula is breaking.I believe it is somewhere along the lines because of the relationship between the two tables in PowerBI.

Let me know if I need to furnish more details.Please find the links to the excel base data and Power BI File that may assist.

Excel - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifqq493hvw781ub/Test.pbix?dl=0

PowerBI - https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cmm6vpbpxwh0bo/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Please provide some sample (minimum with all scenario) data and then explain what you need from them.

Comment: Most important what is missing in your question is your DAX formula...

Comment: Apologies - neglected to add the formula. Edited the post.